# How to control Raspberry Pi PiNoIR camera via python?

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

I have a PiNoIR camera for a Raspberry Pi (using Raspbian), and I'd like to control it through a python script. I tried to use the `picamera` python (2.7) library, but it doesn't work. The camera is enabled in Raspberry Pi, and it seems to work well (as tested by `raspivid -t 0` in the terminal). However, this simple python script freezes all the time and even `CTRL+C` is unble to stop the process, I need to terminate it from a new window by `sudo kill`

```
import time
import picamera
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)
    camera.capture('/home/pi/test.jpg')
    camera.stop_preview()
```

The same script works fine with the standard (non infrared) Pi Camera though. The documentation http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.5/# doesn't seem to say anything specific about the PiNoIR camera board.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: This is interesting, as the PiNoIR should be the same camera just without the IR filter. So, your problem does not sand as if it had anything to do with the IR feature. If you have two cameras, are they of the same revision? (Can be seen on the PCB)? Also, double check that you can repeat the behaviour with the two cameras.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. yes, both cameras have the same revision number (1.3). The script failed to execute several times even after  update and reboot. Then it worked with the standard camera. However, when I tried the IR camera again it worked... So maybe that was just a connection issue, but then how come I could see the screen via `raspivid`...? Strange. Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line: camera.stop_preview(). You can then stop the running script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>